# How to put dynamic width on td in tr with inserted data

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using table with 100% width and in that I am having table row with two table data like this as given below:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" >
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;" class="fontbold fontgrey">Data1 :<span class="fontdgrey">Rs. </span></td>
      <td width="15">&#160;</td>
      <td style="width:200px;" class="fontbold fontgrey">Data2 :<span class="fontdgrey">Rs. </span></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

its output is like this:

**Data1   Rs.       Data2    Rs.**

that is fine with me but if I increase the text length, it is not coming in correct format like this

**InsertedNewData          InsertedNewData2

Rs                       Rs.**

so I want to increase the td width dynamically with content inserted into it with the single line  as below:

**InsertedNewData     Rs.100000           InsertedNewData2     Rs. 1000000**

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi used to this    .fontbold.fontgrey{word-wrap: break-word;}

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Code that you have posted seems to behave like you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Utc/

Comment: @PavloMykhalov        see the output ,,,not coming in correct fommat in first td rs is coming in next line ...

Comment: why negative marks for this question .......

Comment: I see the output on my fiddle. Table extends to fit the content. What "output" are you talking about? If you are asking about HTML, you need to provide HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `style='width:150px;` and `style='width:250px`
and the td element becomes dynamic since you have the table element width 100%